# Mostrar datos json con plugin jquery DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

intento mostrar los datos que vienen de la API de marvel dentro de un DataTables Plugin de Jquery, pero me acaba diciendo loading... y no muestra sus datos.

```
 var ts = Date.now();
 var publicKey = ' ' // por seguridad no van las apis en este codigo
 var privatekey = ' ' // por seguridad no van las apis en este codigo
 var hash = $.md5(ts + privatekey + publicKey);


 $.get({
     url : 'https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?' + "&ts=" + ts + "&apikey=" + publicKey + "&hash=" + hash,
     success : function(respuesta) {
        console.log(respuesta);
     }
 });

            $('#tabla').dataTable({
                "json": "(respuesta.data.results)",

                "columns" : [ 
                    { "data": "id" },
                    { "data": "name" },
                    { "data": "description" },
                ]
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías configurar el `DataTable` para que haga directamente la llamada `ajax`:

- `ajax.cache`: seteado a `true`, para desactivar el parámetro `_`
- `ajax.url`: para indicar la fuente de datos
- `ajax.dataSrc`: para indicar donde estan los registros en la respuesta.
- [Opcional] [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render): Para customizar la visualización de datos.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
var ts = Date.now();
var publicKey = prompt('Ingresa tu clave pública:'); // por seguridad no van las keys en este codigo
var privatekey = prompt('Ingresa tu clave privada:'); // por seguridad no van las keys en este codigo
var hash = $.md5(ts + privatekey + publicKey);

$('#tabla').dataTable({
  ajax: {
    cache: true,
    url: `https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?&ts=${ts}&apikey=${publicKey}&hash=${hash}`,
    dataSrc: 'data.results'
  },
  columns: [{
    "data": "id"
  }, {
    "render": function(v, t, data) {
      return `<img width="100" src="${data.thumbnail.path + '.' + data.thumbnail.extension}"/>`;
    }
  }, {
    "data": "name"
  }, {
    "data": "description"
  }]
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.md5@1.0.2/index.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="tabla" class="display" style="width:100%"></table>
```

---

#### Referencias:

- [DataTable `ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax)

Comment: Funciona perfecto, gracias. Una pequeña duda; ¿Cómo lo hago con esta ruta de imágen para incluirla dentro de un "data:"  ```imagen_personaje.attr('src', personaje.thumbnail.path + '/landscape_small.' + personaje.thumbnail.extension)```

Comment: @SebaLagos, actualice mi respuesta para darte un ejemplo de como hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto, solo cambia el id de la tabla y pon los nombres de las columnas

```
    $.ajax({
    url : 'https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters',
    type: 'GET',
    data: { 
        ts : ts, 
        apikey : apikey,
        hash : hash,
    } ,
    success : function(data) {                    
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        dt = $('#tabla').DataTable( {
            "bDestroy": true,
            "aaData": data,
            "lengthMenu": [ [10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50,100,"Todos"]],
            "aoColumns": [
                { "mData": "columna1" },
                { "mData": "columna2" },
                { "mData": "columna3" },
                { "mData": "columna4" },
            ]
        })
    }
   }):
```